# cannot be resolved or is not a field with some EditTexts

Tags: java, android

Ok so i have the following situation : I create some Editexts dynamically and i want to add another row of Editexts when one of the EditTexts from the last row is clicked.
I tried doing it the following way :

When the last row of EditTexts is created,i assign each of them an id 
  `et.setId(997);
    et.setId(998);
    et.setId(999);`

I declared each of them ;
`public EditText camp1;
public EditText camp2;
public EditText camp3;`

```
camp1 = (EditText) findViewById(997);
camp2 = (EditText) findViewById(998);
camp3 = (EditText) findViewById(999);

camp1.setOnClickListener(this);
camp2.setOnClickListener(this);
camp3.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And when i try to do this
    `case R.id.camp1:`
inside a switch i get `"camp1 cannot be resolved or is not a field"`
What am i doing wrong ? 
Is there a better way to detect when the last Edittext is clicked and create a new one ?

EDIT:

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        TextWatcher {

```
public Button paginanoua;
// public Button calculeaza;
public Button produsnou;
public EditText camp1;
public EditText camp2;
public EditText camp3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    produsnou();
    paginanoua = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paginanoua);
    // calculeaza = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculeaza);
    produsnou = (Button) findViewById(R.id.produsnou);
    camp1 = (EditText) findViewById(997);
    camp2 = (EditText) findViewById(998);
    camp3 = (EditText) findViewById(999);
    paginanoua.setOnClickListener(this);
    // calculeaza.setOnClickListener(this);
    produsnou.setOnClickListener(this);
    camp1.setOnClickListener(this);
    camp2.setOnClickListener(this);
    camp3.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId())
    {
    case R.id.paginanoua:
    ShowDialog();


    case R.id.produsnou:
        produsnou();

case R.id.997:///error
produsnou();

}
}

private void ShowDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Pagina noua..");
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Sigur doriti o pagina noua?");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Da",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Am inceput o lista noua", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Nu",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Ramanem la lista curenta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

List<EditText> allpret = new ArrayList<EditText>();
List<EditText> allcant = new ArrayList<EditText>();
List<Float> alltotal = new ArrayList<Float>();
float totaltest = 0;

public void produsnou() {
    LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setHint("Produs");
    l1.addView(et);
    et.addTextChangedListener(this);
    et.setId(997);

    LinearLayout l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
    EditText et2 = new EditText(this);
    et2.setHint("Cantitate");
    et2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
            | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    et2.setId(998);

    allcant.add(et2);
    l2.addView(et2);
    et2.addTextChangedListener(this);

    LinearLayout l3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout3);
    EditText et3 = new EditText(this);
    et3.setHint("Pret");
    et3.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
            | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
    l3.addView(et3);
    et3.setId(999);
    allpret.add(et3);
    et3.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

float temp = 0;

public void calculeaza() {
    totaltest = 0;
    String[] cant = new String[allcant.size()];

    for (int j = 0; j < allcant.size(); j++) {

        cant[j] = allcant.get(j).getText().toString();
        if (cant[j].matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Ati omis cantitatea de pe pozitia " + (j + 1),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            cant[j] = Float.toString(0);

        }
    }

    String[] pret = new String[allcant.size()];
    for (int k = 0; k < allpret.size(); k++) {
        pret[k] = allpret.get(k).getText().toString();
        if (pret[k].matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Ati omis pretul de pe pozitia " + (k + 1),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pret[k] = Float.toString(0);

        }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < allpret.size(); l++) {

        Float temp = Float.parseFloat(cant[l]) * Float.parseFloat(pret[l]);
        alltotal.add(temp);
        totaltest = totaltest + temp;
        // totaluri[l] = temp ; }

        TextView totalf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        totalf.setText(String.format("Total: %.2f", totaltest));

    }
}

// Float[] totaluri = new Float[allcant.size()];

public void reload(View v) {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
    calculeaza();
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    calculeaza();

}
```

}

Comment: Why would `R.id.camp1` work? You didn't declare that ID anywhere, right?

Comment: Have you tried using case:997, case:998... etc. ?

Comment: I'm a beginner,maybe i'm wrong but didn't i declare it here : camp1 = (EditText) findViewById(997);

Comment: Shobhit,yea,doesn't work.

Comment: What does your `onClick()` method do? (Show the code please!)

Answer (score 0):

All you care about is the last editText, right?  Just give the last editText an onClickListener that creates another editText.  Then give the new editText the onClickListener and remove it from the the previous "last one".

like this:

camp1 = (EditText) findViewById(997);
camp2 = (EditText) findViewById(998);
camp3 = (EditText) findViewById(999);

camp1.setOnClickListener(this);
camp2.setOnClickListener(this);
camp3.setOnClickListener(new myListener());

...

//put this private class in the same activity as the stuff above
    private class myListener implements View.OnClickListener {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText editText = new EditText(YourActivityName.this);
        editText.setOnClickListener(new myListener());
        //TODO put it in your viewGroup

        //Give the old EditText your standard onClickListener
        view.setOnClickListener(YourActivityName.this);
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setId()` does *not* add any variables to the `R.id` class because `setId()` executes at run-time, but `R` is generated at compile-time.  Since you are creating dynamic views, you need to rethink your `onClick()` method. You might want to consider using a `ListView` to help you. You can also set up the three `TextView`s using a separate XML file, such as `row.xml`.